# IAP purchase notification showing wrong price of item

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

While testing my IAP store implementation[sandbox]. I purchased an item , I got purchase alert for confirmation [cancel/Buy]. But the price of the item is wrong . There is a specific way to reproduce it.

1] Tap on an item shown in the store.Wait for the purchase confirmation alert.

2] As the purchase confirmation alert appears , tap on BUY and quickly turn of the wi-fi connection.So that internet connection is disabled and transaction is failed.

3] Once transaction failed Alert appears, enable the internet connection and purchase same item again.

Now most of the times price info I get on purchase Confirmation Alert is more than what actually it is.

and occasionally it shows message :

> This item is currently being modified.Please try again later

Has anybody experienced such problem ? and What I can do at my end to resolve it ?

PS:I am testing on iOS7.

Edit 1:

It also shows message like :

> you have already purchased this but it hasn't been downloaded

EDIT 2:

Can you guys please check same thing at your end. Just to confirm if the same problem occurs ?

EDIT 3:

On getting the items from server . I logged the price of the item I tap to buy. The log shows correct value , but when Purchase confirmation alert appears , it shows wrong value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

It started as just wrong price (tested on Australia Tier1-3 prices which appears as Alternate Tier1-3 priced), and I submitted it as bug to Apple.

Then a few days after prices in the Confirm dialog sometimes appear as correct, sometimes wrong.

The "being modified" is new, maybe they're fixing it. It seems it affects several items.
Maybe a flaw that came with the new IAP price changes.